# Android ViewAnimator : animation while changing viewstub child

Tags: android, android-layout, z-index, android-animation, viewanimator

Here's my problem :

I've got a ViewAnimator like :

```
<ViewAnimator
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewanimator">

    <ViewStub
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/form_viewstub"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/form_view"
        android:layout="@layout/form_layout"/>

    <ViewStub
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/history_viewstub"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/history_view"
        android:layout="@layout/history_layout"/>

    <ViewStub
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/call_viewstub"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/call_view"
        android:layout="@layout/call_layout"/>

</ViewAnimator>
```

When I'm animating a viewstub that is after the current, there is no problem. The problem is that when I try to animate a viewstub before, I can't see the animation. Here's a concrete example :

When I try to animate `id/history_viewstub` with the following animation and `id/call_viewstub` is the current displayed layout I do not see anything (I imagine that the animation is played behin the current view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="1.0"
        android:pivotY="0.0"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:duration="600"/>
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

Anybody has already faced this problem ?

Is there a way to specify a `z-index` to the viewstubs like in web development ?

---

**Edit**

Using the `ZAdjustment` property doesn't correct the problem

Comment: Are you using `showPrevious()` and `showNext()` along with `setInAnimation` and `setOutAnimation`?

Comment: No, I'm using setDisplayedChild(int index)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've already solved this problem, but since there isn't an answer...you should be able to use `android:zAdjustment="top"`.

Comment: Not resoled yet... I'll try your suggestion tomorrow, for sure. I have to set it programmatically because I don't know the view that have to be on top... I'll let you know as I try ;)

Comment: Any luck using setZAdjustment(ZORDER_TOP)?

Comment: Not solving the problem as I mentioned it when I edited Oct 22 '11 at 11:19

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [View.bringToFront](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront%28%29).

This method will move your view to the end of the childs list. So its and other views index will change. Be careful about this.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you are not actually using the functionality of the `ViewAnimator` class but rather just the inherited `FrameLayout` class.

To animate view transitions you need to set the `android:inAnimation` and `android:outAnimation` properties on the `ViewAnimator` and initiate the transitions from your code using either `setDisplayedChild()` or `showNext()` and `showPrevious()`.

Comment: So I have to use FrameLayout instead of ViewAnimator ?

Comment: Because I'm already using `viewAnimator.setInAnimation(inAnim);` and `viewAnimator.setOutAnimation(outAnim);`, the problem is that if the viewstub I want to animate is placed before the current displayed child, the animation occurs behind the current displayed child...